# Upload de imagem profile photo e associar ao atributo "profilePhoto" na entidade User com Spring

Tags: java, api, spring, spring-boot

Tenho um entidade dessa forma:

Estou usando Spring Boot e no Postman para instanciar novos objetos da classe User

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cod_user")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "birthday")
    private LocalDate birthday;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_address", unique = true)
    private Address address;

    private ??? profilePhoto;
```

Minha dúvida é: Como fazer o upload de uma imagem e associar ao atributo profilePhoto, pra quando eu for instanciar um novo objeto já poder inserir essa imagem de perfil na criação do usuário?

OBSERVAÇÃO: Não estou usando Spring MVC ou Thymeleaf, apenas o Spring Boot e fazendo as requisições via Postman, que no caso para criar uma nova instancia estou passando um JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Gui",
    "gender": "male",
    "birthday": "1998-12-12",
    "address":{
        "address": "Rua da Neves",
        "city": "Niterói",
        "state": "Rio de Janeiro",
        "postalCode": "579777-90",
        "country": "Brazil"
    },
    "profilePhoto": ???
```

Como eu posso passar no meu User Controller uma forma de criar essa imagem e associar ao atributo profilePhoto?

```
@PostMapping("/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Person create(@RequestBody Person person) { 
    return personService.create(person); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: A foto você envia através do form-data]

O restante do seu JSON vc envia no corpo da requisição normalmente.

Answer (score -2):

1 - Devido a indexação, recomendo deixar essa imagem em um S3 ou outro storage e persistir apenas um identificador.

2 - Para persistir a imagem, não sei se consegues mandar a imagem dentro de um DTO, lembro que tem alguns problemas para o tratamento, mas esse código abaixo é funcional.

```java
   @PostMapping
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createCustomer(@RequestParam(name = "image", required = false) MultipartFile image,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "fullName", required = false) String fullName,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "socialId", required = false) String socialId,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "gener", required = false) String gener,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "civilStatus", required = false) String civilStatus,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "age", required = false) Integer age,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "dependents", required = false) Integer dependents,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "state", required = false) String state,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "telephone", required = false) String telephone,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "email", required = false)String email){

        try {
            CustomerDto customerDto = this.
                    getCustomerDto(image,
                            fullName,
                            socialId,
                            gener,
                            civilStatus,
                            age,
                            dependents,
                            state,
                            telephone,
                            email);

            Customer customer = this.costumerService.createCustomer(customerDto);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(customer,HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Erro no servidor", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Se quiser o exemplo completo.
https://github.com/GuilhermeCesar/cadastros-clientes-back/blob/master/src/main/java/com/essencia/resources/CustomerResource.java